# Obtain youtube channel id without display name

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I wasn't exactly sure how to word the title, but I'm creating an API that retrieves certain JSON date about a persons Youtube channel, and it works fine and dandy until I come across a channel like this,
 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRMZyEp0IzcI0IGpDFRh6fQ

where his account ID is in the url instead of
https://www.youtube.com/user/iceycat25.

When I run the API and I search for "iceycat25" the data is pulled normally like it should, but if I search for "*MOTO TIME*" the API returns no such user exists. Is there any way to fix this?
Here's the relevant code I have as of right now.

```
// obtain your own API key at
// https://console.developers.google.com
$MyKey = xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx;
// Convert the GET data into variables.
$YoutubeName = $_GET["Channel_Name"];
$Command = $_GET["Command"];

// Get the channel ID and Upload ID from the YouTube name inputted
$IDs = json_decode(@file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=$YoutubeName&key=$MyKey"), true);
if($IDs['items'][0]['id'] == null)
{
    echo 'No such YouTube channel exists.';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented it in my forum as a `div`.
As you see here the YouTube API and doesn't accept usernames and IDs in the same parameter.

With ID:

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-***channelid***="CHANNELID" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

With Username:

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-***channel***="{$user.customFields.youtube_us}" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

You have to change the attributes.

Just try it with `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=$YoutubeName&key=$MyKey`, it should work, if not - leave a comment.

More: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#examples

Comment: Yes,seems so. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Comment: If I just use `id=$YoutubeName` versus `forUsername=$YoutubeName` nothing shows up when I search for "iceycat25" nor "MOTO TIME". This is requiring me to know the channel ID before hand. Which in retrospect having the end user supply their own channel ID is better, since Display names aren't unique, and they could be pulling data for the wrong user. I'll just mark this accepted. Thanks for trying to help!